# How can I implement this counting sort pseudocode in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pseudocode

I have been trying to implement this counting sort pseudocode in python but I haven't been successful. How can I fix it?

```
functionCountingSort(A,k)
    C ← newVector[k + 1]
    R ← newVector[Length(A)]
    pos ← 0
    for 0 ≤ j < Length(A)do
        C[A[j]] ← C[A[j]] + 1
    end for
   for 0 ≤ i < k+1 do
       for pos ≤ r < pos + C[i] do
           R[r] ← i
        end for
      pos ← r
   end for
 return R 
end function
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmelR.png)

My own attempt.

```
def countingSort(arr):
size = len(arr)
k = max(arr)
k_1 = k + 1
pos = 0

# Count array
C = [0] * k_1 

# Output array
R = [0] * size

for j in range(0, size):
    C[arr[j]] = C[arr[j]] + 1

for i in range(0, k_1):
    for pos in range(r, pos + C[i])
         R[r[i]] = i
    pos = r

return R
```

data = [4, 2, 2, 8, 3, 3, 1]
countingSort(data)
print("Sorted Array in Ascending Order: ")
print(data)

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `r` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for pos in range(r, pos + C[i])
  R[r[i]] = i
```

seem to be

```py
for r in range(pos, pos + C[i])
  R[r] = i
```

if your pseudo-code is right.

Comment: I just check your implement from the pseudo-code. Hope it will help you.